# scipy.integrate.ode with numpy.view

Tags: python, numpy, pointers, scipy

I try to solve 2 coupled equations systems, called here system A and system B. One of these 2 systems are an ODE system. 
To avoid to copy the shared data between the 2 systems, I would like have a structure with pointers. To that, I use the mechanism of numpy.view.

A bit of code :

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

t0,t1,dt = 0.0,5.0, 1.0

data = np.ones((5,2))
data[:,1]*=2

y=np.array([0.0,0.0])     ### no matter default value

r = scipy.integrate.ode(f)
r.set_integrator('dopri5', rtol=1e-3, atol=1e-6 )
r.set_f_params(0.05)

#r.set_initial_value(y, t0); r._y = data[2]   ### Apparently equivalent
r.set_initial_value(data[2], t0)                   ### Apparently equivalent

print(np.shares_memory(r.y,y))
print(np.shares_memory(r.y,data))
```

Here, at the initial state, I have a synchronization between r.y (system A) and data[2] (the variable named data is the data of system B). If I modify one, the other is also modified and vice versa. Tape the command r.y.base confirm that r.y is just a view of the array named data. That the behavior that I desired.

Now, the problem start here. If I make progress my EDO system :

```
while r.successful() and r.t < t1:
    r.integrate(r.t+dt, step=True)
    print(r.t+dt,r.y)

print(np.shares_memory(r.y,data))     
print(data)
```

data and r.y are no more synchronized. r.y are no more a view of data.
It looks that the integrate function creates a new instance of its attribute r.y rather than just update it. I have read the source code of this function

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/integrate/_ode.py#L396

but it rapidly refers to fortran code, and my understanding abilities stop here.

How can I solve (or got round) this problem by a different way of the data copy between r.y and data (that also implies a manual management of the synchronisation) ?
Is it possible that is a bug in scipy ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't see anything the `ode` documentation (or code) that promises in-place changes to `y0`, the initial value array.  `ode.integrate` has `self._y, self.t = mth(...,  self._y, self.t,...), not `self._y[:] = mth(...)`.  It's possible that `mth` could return a `view` input `_y`, but unlikely.  And especially if it passed on to FORTRAN code.  `numpy` only promises `shares_memory` under selected indexing operations.

Comment: Defining `r.y` as a property, is a way of saying 'The underlying `_y` is ours to use.  The user shouldn't count on any undocumented behavior.'

Comment: Yes you are right, it's unlikely to conserve the shares_memory behavior. But what is the expected behavior of the integrate function when the ode instance is initialized with a view ? I want to say that the initial structure should be preserve, especially if nothing indicates the contrary on documentation. Maybe, should I report a bug to the authors ?

Comment: I don't see what difference it makes.  Just because `y0` is a view of `data`, doesn't change the relationship between that and later values of `_y`.  `_y` references a new array at each step.